# Wildfly H2 db driver override oracle jdbc with xa-datasource

Tags: oracle, exception, h2, wildfly, jta

I'm working on Wildfly 9.X playing with JTA transaction.

I'm able to get the UserTransaction by

```
ut = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
```

Then i want to use it with my entity manager got in my dao classes.:
    ut.begin();
    em.joinTransaction();
    em.persist(newUser);
    ut.commit();

But i'm keeing to get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "MAP_USER" not found; SQL statement:
insert into MAP_USER (ADS_USER, BAD_PASSWORD_COUNT, COST_CENTRE, DB_PASSWORD, DB_USER, department, email, ENABLED_YN, EXPIRING_DATE, EXTERNAL_ID, EXTERNAL_LAST_SYNC, EXTERNAL_REPOSITORY , fax, FULL_NAME, LAST_BAD_PASSWORD, LAST_LOGIN, LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE, password, PASSWORD_HISTORY, PROFILE_CODE, PROFILE_CODE_COMMENT, PROFILE_USER_YN, tel, USER_COMMENT, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4864)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4842)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:974)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:375)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:428)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:377)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:644)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:800)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:786)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 87 more
```

this is my datasource:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KasOracleDS" pool-name="KasOracleDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
                </xa-datasource-property>                    
                <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                    <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
                </xa-pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user</user-name>
                    <password>pwd</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

and i have successfully installe the ojdbc6 driver as wildfly module.

Why the error is risen up by h2? What the datasource it is trying to connect?

**EDITED**

I have declared my entity manager by this code lines:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            EntityManagerFactory emfByJoss = (EntityManagerFactory)ctx.lookup(dao.getPersistenceJNDIUnitName());

EntityManager em = emfByJoss.createEntityManager(getJPAPropertiesForJboss(principal.getDataSource()));

private Properties getJPAPropertiesForJboss(String dataSourcePath) {  
    Properties properties = new Properties(); 
    properties.put ("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"); 
    properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource", dataSourcePath); 
    return properties;  
}
```

Datasource path is the jndi name of my datasource created inside wildfly, while persistence xml is:

```
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="KAS-Mapping-AppHandled">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>com.my.MapUser</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Bind entity manager factory to JNDI at java:jboss/myEntityManagerFactory -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/EntityManagerFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

i m forced to do this way as datasource have to be dynamic and change at runtime.

Comment: Did you specify a datasource in your persistence.xml file? If not you will likely get the default one.

Comment: i have updated my post... so you can see how i create my entitymanager